# Helm Template check boolean value

Tags: go, templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to check if a value is true or not, but for every variation that I try, the error below is always shown:

```
_helpers.tpl:96:19: executing "mongo_databasename" at <.Values.mongo.enabled>: can't evaluate field Values in type string
```

Part of my _helpers.tpl file:

```
{{/*
Get mongodb connection string
*/}}
{{- define "mongo_databasename" -}}
{{-  if eq (.Values.mongo.enabled | toString) "true" }}
{{-  .Values.mongo.databaseName }}
{{- else }}
{{-  .Values.environmentVars.mongo.databaseName }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

The respective part of my values.yaml file:

```
mongo:
  enabled:
  username: user
```

I've tried many ways to check the if condition, like the one above:

```
{{-  if .Values.mongo.enabled  }}
```

Comment: How are you calling `mongo_databasename` (what does the `template` or `include` invocation look like; is it inside a `range` loop or something like that)?  My initial read of that error message is that you're passing it something other than the Helm root value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be caused by the scope of include.

The template looks okay.

I tried as follows

_helper.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
Get mongodb connection string
*/}}
{{- define "mongo_databasename" -}}
{{- if .Values.mongo.enabled }}
{{- .Values.mongo.databaseName }}
{{- else }}
{{- .Values.environmentVars.mongo.databaseName }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
mongo:
  enabled:
  username: user
  databaseName: test

environmentVars:
  mongo:
    databaseName: envvar
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  test: {{- include "mongo_databasename" .}}
  test2:
    {{- with .Values.mongo }}
    {{- include "mongo_databasename" $ }}
    {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-v7
data:
  test:envvar
  test2:envvar
```

Pay attention to the scope (`. | $`) passed in at the end of the `templates/configmap.yaml include` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked pretty fine. I'd to have studied better the scope topic.

Comment: ```$``` represents the root element of values, ```.``` represents the element in the current ```range``` loop or ```with```

Answer (score -1):

values.yaml - need add to enabled: "true", this works for me

```
mongo:
  enabled: "true"
  username: user
```